# Eclipse color theme does not recognize files as php

Tags: eclipse

I made a custom theme for coloring php code in Eclipse 3.8. The problem is that all files on the remote server are with .x extension, not with .php extension and the theme doesn't recognize them as php files and the coloring doesn't work. Does anybody know a work around for this problem. How can i tell eclipse to read files with .x extenstions as .php files ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open preferences and go to `General`=>`Editors`=>`File Associations`. In the above list add a new entry `*.x` and for that entry add your php editor in the second list.

Comment: I did that but now i don't have autocomplete for like properties of an object or main php functions like in_array etc. Any idea about that ? 10x

Comment: I foun the solution. If you want you autocomplete to work, you go to your .project file and you add these <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.php.core.PHPNature</nature> inside the <natures></natures> tag. Than you restart eclipse and voala. This is the solution when autocomplete is not working on Remote System Explorer

Answer (score 1):

Go in your menu `Window` -> `preferences`.

Select then `General` -> `Editors` -> `File associations`

Add your `.x` extention (above) if it doesn't exist and then associate the PHP editor (underneath).